# toy story 2 who is the guy who plays as the other buzz lightyear

Tags: toy-story, toy-story-2, toy-story-4

so in toy story 2 there are many many many (buzz lightyear) from  whom (the buzz lightyear) are all from different (places) then the original buzz nor the woody. so who are the actor of these other buzzes if there can only be one person for the ACTUAL buzz.

Comment: I are trying to talk about how can there be many buzz light year if there is only one voice actor. it does not make sence to me because how can he talk to many different toys at one time. from whom he is. nor the buzz.

Comment: One actor can voice any number of characters. Editing can be used to make him converse with himself. As another example, every clone in Star Wars animation has the same voice actor.

Comment: You might look up "sound mixing" -- it's how one person and one microphone, plus a recording system and mixer, can sound like an entire choir.  Queen recorded "The Prophet's Song" this way.

Answer (score 5):

In *Toy Story 2*, veteran voice actor Pat Frahley [plays the voice of “the many many many” Toy Store Buzz Lightyears](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0120363/fullcredits/cast?ref_=m_ttfc_3), a different role from “Andy’s Buzz.” In fact, Frahley’s role is precisely credited by IMDB in the plural as “Toy Store Buzz Lightyears.”

“Andy’s Buzz” has been, and is voiced in *Toy Story 2*, by Tim Allen (a completely different guy).

Comment: @Montvbz It’s no big thing: Darth Vader’s been portrayed by at least nine different actors, and that’s just including on film and not getting into all of the video games.

Comment: but how because dark vadar is only one person there cant be NINE

Comment: Films like Toy Story 2 and Star Wars are works of fiction, not documentaries. Actors playing fictional roles are then chosen to portray their fictional characters or roles based on a wide variety of reasons. Some actors are chosen for appearance. Some for voice. Some for capturing essential elements of the character. In some cases, several people may have that element and both, or more may get to play the part. The best actors are those who allow the viewers to suspend their disbelief and accept the fictional person to be real, or could be real if the fiction was able to be reality.

Comment: so technicly i can be whoever i want and people will believe me

Comment: Of course. However be aware that whether anyone else _believes you_ may not entirely be in your control. For example, belief in your portrayal may be strengthened by a press release from Disney or Pixar or Marvel Entertainment announcing your part, versus you putting on a homemade costume and announcing your role yourself in your local bank or grocery store, and at that point you might have to convince police of your identity too. Also, stick to fictional characters rather than real people, for purpose of entertainment and not fraud.